# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row when inserting multiple rows

Tags: oracle11g

I am trying to assign or give all permissions of a user to another given user, `13053` but facing this Oracle error, `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` and i know exactly which part of my SQL statement shown below is returning this error but failed to handle it because what i want to achieve is to give those multiple rows returned to the given user with an id of `13053`.

**My attempt**

```
INSERT INTO userpermissions (
     userid,permissionid
) VALUES (
     13053,( SELECT permissionid
        FROM userpermissions
        WHERE userid = ( SELECT userid
                         FROM users
                         WHERE username = '200376'
                       )
      )
);
```

Any help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rewrite ought to do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO USERPERMISSIONS(
  USERID,
  PERMISSIONID
)
 SELECT 13053 AS USERID,
        p.PERMISSIONID
   FROM USERPERMISSIONS p
  WHERE p.userid = (SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username = '200376');
```

The problem with the original insert is that you are using single-row insert syntax when you are really trying to insert a set of rows.

Including the target userid as a literal is one way to make the set of rows look the way I am assuming you intend.

Comment: thanks for helping me with the right answer.  But what if giving those permissions to multiple users instead of a single user indicated as a literal?

Comment: @CCC, what do you mean? Do you want to write a SQL statement that grants the privs of user 200376 to a short list of users (e.g. 13053, 13054, and 13055) or are you trying for a more general solution?

Comment: a SQL statement that grants the privs of user 200376 to a short list of users (e.g. 13053, 13054, and 13055) by assuming this short list  will be from another table.